# Angular Transfer State not preventing repeat http calls

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I have the http request being made a service which is injected onto my component and subscribed to from there. Since I introduced server side rendering with angular universal to my application, the results on the page are repeated at least twice.

I have method which is called on click, which performs the http request to facebook's api

```
getAlbum(albumId: number) {

    this.albumPhotos = this.state.get(ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY, null as any);

    if (!this.albumPhotos) {
      this.facebookService.getBachadiffAlbumPhotos(albumId).subscribe(res => {
        this.bachataPicsArray = res;
        this.state.set(ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY, res as any);
      });
    }
  }
```

I declared the const variable below the imports

```
const ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY = makeStateKey('albumPhotos');
```

And I also declared the property

```
albumNames: any;
```

I am assuming I have done all of the imports right I have the code on [github in the gallery component](https://github.com/Feroli/bachadiff/blob/master/src/app/gallery/gallery.component.ts).

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are on the right pass, you just need to handle your service differently if you are on the server or the browser side to perform your queries only once and not twice.

Pseudo logic:

- If server -> Do http request -> Set value in transfer-state
- If browser -> Get value from transfer-state

To do so, you could for example enhance your Service like following:

```
@Injectable()
export class FacebookEventsService {
    const ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY: StateKey<number>;

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, private http: HttpClient) {
       this.ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY = makeStateKey('albumPhotos');
    } 

    getBachaDiffFacebookEvents(): Observable<CalendarEvent[]> {
        // Here we check if server or browser side
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            return this.getServerBachaDiffFacebookEvents();
        } else {
            return this.getBrowserBachaDiffFacebookEvents();
        }
    }

    getServerBachaDiffFacebookEvents(): Observable<CalendarEvent[]> {

           return this.http.get(this.facebookEventsUrl)
             .map(res => {

                  // Here save also result in transfer-state
                  this.transferState.set(ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY, calendarEvents);

             });
     }


        getBrowserBachaDiffFacebookEvents(): Observable<CalendarEvent[]> {
           return new Observable(observer => {
            observer.next(this.transferState.get(ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY, null));
          });
     }
}
```

**UPDATE**

To use this logic you would also need:

1. `TransferHttpCacheModule` (to be initialized in app.module.ts).

> TransferHttpCacheModule installs a Http interceptor that avoids
>   duplicate HttpClient requests on the client, for requests that were
>   already made when the application was rendered on the server side.

https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/common

2. `ServerTransferStateModule` on the server side and `BrowserTransferStateModule` on the client side to use TransferState

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState

P.S.: Note that if you do so and enhance your server, of course you would not need anymore to set the value in transfer-state in your getAlbum() method you displayed above

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to handle the server and browser side as you did in your `gallery.component.ts`, you could do something like the following:

```
getAlbum(albumId: number) {

    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {

      if (!this.albumPhotos) {
        this.facebookService.getBachadiffAlbumPhotos(albumId).subscribe(res => {
          this.bachataPicsArray = res;
          this.state.set(ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY, null);
        });
      }
    } else {

      this.albumPhotos = this.state.get(ALBUM_PHOTOS_KEY,null);
    }

  }
```

**UPDATE 3**

The thing is, your action **getAlbum** is never called on the server side. This action is only used on the browser side, once the page is rendered, when the user click on a specific action. Therefore, using transfer-state in that specific case isn't correct/needed.

Furthermore not sure that the Observable in your service was correctly subscribed.

Here what to change to make it running:

`gallery.component.ts`

```
getAlbum(albumId: number) {

    this.facebookService.getBachadiffAlbumPhotos(albumId).subscribe(res => {
        this.albumPhotos = res;
    });
  }
```

`facebook-events.service.ts`

```
getBachadiffAlbumPhotos(albumId: number): Observable<Object> {

    this.albumId = albumId;
    this.facebookAlbumPhotosUrl =    `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/${this.albumId}/photos?limit=20&fields=images,id,link,height,width&access_token=${this.accessToken}`;

    return    Observable.fromPromise(this.getPromiseBachaDiffAlbumPhotos(albumId));
  }

private getPromiseBachaDiffAlbumPhotos(albumId: number): Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.facebookAlbumPhotosUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/${this.albumId}/photos?limit=20&fields=images,id,link,height,width&access_token=${this.accessToken}`;

      let facebookPhotos: FacebookPhoto[] = new Array();
      let facebookPhoto: FacebookPhoto;

      const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
      this.http.get(this.facebookAlbumPhotosUrl, {params: params})
        .subscribe(res => {

          let facebookPhotoData = res['data'];

          for (let photo of facebookPhotoData) {

            facebookPhotos.push(
              facebookPhoto = {
                id: photo.id,
                image: photo.images[3].source,
                link: photo.link,
                height: photo.height,
                width: photo.width
              });
          }

          resolve(facebookPhotos);
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE 4**

ngOnInit is executed on the server side, this means that my very first answer here has to be use in this case.

Furthermore, also note that on the server side you doesn't have access to the window, therefore calling `$`

With `gallery.component.ts` you could do something like this to run only the http queries once but this won't solve all your problems, I think it will still need further improvements.

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.facebookService.getBachadiffFacebookVideos().subscribe(res => {
        this.bachataVidsArray = res;
        this.state.set(VIDEOS_KEY, res as any);
      });


  this.facebookService.getBachadiffFacebookLastClassPictures().subscribe(res => {
        this.bachataPicsArray = res;
        this.state.set(LAST_CLASS_PICTURES_KEY, res as any);
      });

      this.facebookService.getBachadiffAlbumNames().subscribe(res => {
        this.bachataAlbumHeaderNames = res;
        this.state.set(ALBUM_NAMES_KEY, res as any);
      });
    } else {
      $('ul.tabs').tabs();

      this.bachataVidsArray = this.state.get(VIDEOS_KEY, null as any);
      this.bachataPicsArray = this.state.get(LAST_CLASS_PICTURES_KEY, null as any);
      this.bachataAlbumHeaderNames = this.state.get(ALBUM_NAMES_KEY, null as any);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I don't get any value back from this.transfer.get

Comment: Did you initialized TransferState on both side respectively `ServerTransferStateModule` on the server side and `BrowserTransferStateModule` on the browser side? See https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState

Comment: Also did you add `TransferHttpCacheModule` wich is also needed for avoiding the duplicate requests https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/common`

Comment: I added these to my above answer. Let me know @FernandoAnia if this does the tricks

Comment: I added the TransferHttpCacheModule but adding it to the list of imports but I am still not getting anything back from the transferState

Comment: Did you add ServerTransferStateModule and BrowserTransferStateModule too? Did you debug your server side respectively on this side are you sure that you added the results in TransferState?

Comment: Yes I added both modules. As for debugging the [server side](https://github.com/Feroli/bachadiff/blob/master/server.ts) (link to my server file in github), I am not sure what to test in there.

Comment: just found this [issue on github] (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20638) regarding the transfer state module and angular 5.

Comment: I tried to clone your project but I faced some other error so I wasn't able to really debug your problem. But from what I see, 1. you didn't added `TransferHttpCacheModule` or at least it isn't committed. 2. You are missing the `isPlatformServer` part (see above code). I edited my solution to display what I mean

Comment: I pushed the changes now to the repository. To run it do npm install, npm run build:ssr, and finally node dist/server.js

Comment: @FernandoAnia and to test I should just access the menu/tab "Gallery" right?

Comment: yes, and click on the tabs under the pictures of the class header to active the getAlbum method

Comment: @FernandoAnia see **UPDATE 3** in my above solution. No need of transfer-state in this case, the action will only be triggered on the browser side. See the updated code, worked for me, it was only triggered once respectively only one http query

Comment: It runs, but I am back to the original problem. If you scroll down the pictures you will see that they are repeated. This only started happening after I added server side rendering.

Comment: don't know what you mean, in my case one one query is run only if I click on the href link, nothing more

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I mean, this happens when I click the last tab to the right. The images are repeated, but if you debug the request you see that only 13 pictures are retrieved not 26.

Comment: See **UPDATE 4**, on OnNgInit you have to use transfer-state and to check on which side you are executing the code, server or browser side. This will run the queries only once. I think that this answer your question. Cheers

Comment: State transfer is working for me however duplicates http calls are still in network log. Isit expected

Comment: ffs can someone make a repo with weather api and http?