# The dicision boundary between Angular & Angular Universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am working with `Angular 6.1.0`. The problem I am trying out the demo on Server Side Rendering via the [official doc here](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

They say, it's angular Universal meaning:

> A normal Angular application executes in the browser, rendering pages in the DOM in response to user actions. Angular Universal generates static application pages on the server through a process called server-side rendering (SSR). You can easily prepare an app for server-side rendering using the Angular CLI.

Now I have an angular application that has a bunch of screens and some kinda UI flow with user interaction. More of a `PWA (Progressive Web App)` than a website.

The application contains user log-ins that are completely static and is the landing view. The application contains dynamic views as well like views with charts and views that need calling APIs to fetch data.

The problem I am facing is that even after `gzip`, `--prod` & almost all things from a bunch of websites, the time it takes to load the first view (log-in) is around 30-60 seconds.

My questions are:

1. Is it advisable to use SSR, to make the static User Log in page Server Rendered for the application to load quickly?
2. If Yes, Do I need to port my whole Angular Application to Angular Universal? If Yes, is there any link that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side rendering is often helpful for speeding time to initial render. Generally you shouldn't have to change much to add SSR to an angular application, but any direct access of browser apis / dom will need refactoring to abstractions provided by angular. For example you may need to use Renderer2 object (eg: https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/)

The process for adding SSR is documented pretty well at the link you provided to the official docs, and there are a variety of blog posts around it too - just beware of outdated information.

One thing to bear in mind is that unless you use cookie based authentication you won't be able pre-render pages that require a user to be logged in (as you won't have their session information on the server side)

Another option you could look at for improving the startup time of your application is lazy loading of features / routes. You can more information about this here: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: yes I am completely aware of lazy loading and I am using it, thank you for mentioning it and I am using Cookie based sessions as well. I am facing some tough times with the SSR official doc ([my SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973004/server-side-rendering-angular-6-1)). Do you have any link that I can follow on converting my `Angular Application` to `Angular Universal`?

Comment: Yeah I was in the process of writing an answer for that using my app as a reference, but the laptop died haha - will get back to it shortly. I remember the examples being a bit hit and miss

Comment: Not a problem, I look forward to the examples. Thank you very much for taking the time

Comment: I have 1 final question, I have an Angular 6.1.0 application and that has a static log-in screen but rest all screens are dynamic and the Data inside em  is displayed using APIs. My question is do I have to explicitly mention or configure that only the log-in screen has to be SSR'ed and the Rest of the application as is or does the Angular handles it for us? if not is there a blog I can follow?

Comment: So the way it works is that whatever route you first navigate to in the browser will be rendered server side, and then from the point it has loaded in the user's browser control returns to the normal client side angular. This means that if your user bookmarks a dynamic page it will be serverside rendered - and this is where things can get tricky around auth. You can test this for yourself by using chrome's network speed limiter. It's normally possible to transfer state from the SSR rendered page to the client side to avoid making the API requests twice

Comment: For that I've written up code in routing to check if the page needs a log in and if yes, then route him/her to the log in screen. But is there any blog I can follow on transferring state from SSR to client side? I tried googling but I am not sure if I found something of any use

Comment: Have you had a look at the answer on this question? It seems pretty detailed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960049/angular-transfer-state-not-preventing-repeat-http-calls

Comment: @Michael  i am also doing ssr using angular i am facing problem with http only cookie authentication as server does not have client side cookies is there any workaround for the cookies with angular ssr