# Server Side Rendering Angular 6.1

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am working with `Angular 6.1.0` and following the official doc on SSR [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

The problem I am facing is that when I run the command:

> `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

the `serve:ssr` throws me a bunch of errors from the `.spec.ts` files of my `node_modules`.

I've uploaded my project on [`GitHub here`](https://github.com/ImCarrot/ServerSideRenderingDemo) Since I have no idea what's breaking it.

> PS: The source code provided by the official docs also breaks with the same errors. Hence if must be something with my env

### Console Output:

```
PS C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC> npm run build:ssr

> SSR_POC@0.0.0 build:ssr C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC
> npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server


> SSR_POC@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC
> ng build --prod && ng run SSR_POC:server


Date: 2018-12-29T19:36:13.480Z
Hash: 58f58cfef181faaddfa4
Time: 27072ms
chunk {0} runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js (runtime) 1.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.ac3253c328cbe390a1de.js (main) 169 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.677bdac3385565b157aa.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css (styles) 0 bytes [initial] [rendered]

Date: 2018-12-29T19:36:23.462Z
Hash: 884e7c93392763692b9e
Time: 5573ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 22 kB [entry] [rendered]

> SSR_POC@0.0.0 webpack:server C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC
> webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors

Hash: c21ceede9ca319c83513
Version: webpack 4.16.4
Time: 9187ms
Built at: 2018-12-30 01:06:36
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server.js  4.72 MiB       0  [emitted]  server
Entrypoint server = server.js
  [0] ./server.ts 1.91 KiB {0} [built]
  [2] external "events" 42 bytes {0} [built]
  [3] external "fs" 42 bytes {0} [built]
  [4] external "timers" 42 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
  [5] external "crypto" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[210] ./src lazy namespace object 160 bytes {0} [built]
[213] external "url" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[273] external "http" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[274] external "https" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[275] external "os" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[283] external "path" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[292] external "util" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[300] external "net" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[305] external "buffer" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[362] ./src sync 160 bytes {0} [built]
    + 375 hidden modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js 4997:15-36
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./server.ts 5:0-47 10:0-14

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js 5009:15-102
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./server.ts 5:0-47 10:0-14

ERROR in ./server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main.bundle' in 'C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC'
 @ ./server.ts 18:9-45

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts(3,1)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts(6,14)
      TS2345: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(done: any) => Promise<void>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts(10,40)
      TS2345: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(done: any) => Promise<void>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts(12,5)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts(3,1)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts(14,5)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts(19,5)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\src\app\app.component.spec.ts(25,5)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,47)
      TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,90)
      TS1005: '(' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,104)
      TS1005: ']' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,112)
      TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,113)
      TS1136: Property assignment expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,121)
      TS1005: ')' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,147)
      TS1005: '(' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,162)
      TS1005: ']' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,163)
      TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,164)
      TS1136: Property assignment expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,165)
      TS1136: Property assignment expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,179)
      TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,183)
      TS1005: ':' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,208)
      TS1005: '{' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,217)
      TS1005: ':' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,222)
      TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,227)
      TS1005: ':' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,228)
      TS1109: Expression expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(140,230)
      TS1005: ')' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(633,30)
      TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\adity\Desktop\SSR_POC\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(718,1)
      TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! SSR_POC@0.0.0 webpack:server: `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the SSR_POC@0.0.0 webpack:server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-29T19_36_36_231Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! SSR_POC@0.0.0 build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the SSR_POC@0.0.0 build:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-29T19_36_36_276Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you excluding the spec files in the *tsconfig.server.json* files?

Comment: @R.Richards No I am not

Comment: Here are some details on that: https://angular.io/guide/universal#2d-create-a-configuration-file-for-appservermodule

Comment: @R.Richards yes I've gone through that link, I've attached it too in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on one of my projects I was able to figure out a few issues:

In the rules array of webpack.server.config.js I have an additional rule:

```
    {
            // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
            // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
            test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
            parser: {system: true},
    },
```

I believe this is causing some of the warnings you posted around System.import being deprecated.

In server.ts I have

```
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require("./dist/server/main")
```

Which solves can't resolve ./main.bundle error.

Additionally, I think your tsconfig.server.json should look like:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

And finally to solve the jasmine typing errors you need to update typescript to 2.9.x (`npm update typescript`) should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer (+1). I added the `parser` rule and that didn't get rid of the warnings and when I replaced my `test` regex to the one you provided, I was flooded with all sorts of warnings. Additionally can you please add some more insights on the changes in `tsconfig.server.json`? Because it does look somewhat like the one you've shared. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: The typescript update mentioned at the bottom is probably the most important part.

Comment: The changes in tsconfig.server.json primarily change it to extend the normal tsconfig.app.json which excludes the test files anyway. You shouldn't modify the existing rule you had, just add that one to the array (but even without modifying webpack.config updating typescript and fixing the server.ts line should get it building and running)

Comment: yeah the `upgrade typescript` was certainly the big bang of it all. Thank you for that. although the warnings aren't gone just yet. I have updated my source on Git though. Maybe will have to figure something out. thank you.