# SSR with (RE)Hydration in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Angular Universal is for Server side rendering.

I have a full functional Angular app. To increase FCP. I need to hydrate with server side rendering.

Is Angular universal allows dynamic SSR. Loading certain components in server  side ?

I couldn't find anything related to that.(Yes I did some google search on it).

I have found similar topic here,but i need to know more than that.

[The dicision boundary between Angular & Angular Universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972946/the-dicision-boundary-between-angular-angular-universal).

Found some articles related [here](https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive-dc442a6be7b7).

Does it bypass data to back-end or it doesn't care about data,only renders static data ?

Is following scenario possible in angular universal

If I have three components on a page

```
<Comp1></Comp1>
<Comp2><Comp2>
<Comp3><Comp3>
```

Comp1 and Comp3 are mostly static .Comp2 is user specific. I don't want comp2 to be rendered in server side. Comp1 and Comp3 from server rendering and Comp2 on client side.

Comment: Are you asking if SSR will make HTTP requests for server data when it renders the HTML, because the answer is "yes" it fetches server data before it finishes rendering. I think the rule is to wait until all tasks are complete, and I think you can set timeouts and other options.

Comment: will it forward all request from client to the back-end ?. Does it support dynamic rendering ?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic rendering? The back-end will **run** the JavaScript that would have been run in the browser, but on the server in NodeJS. So everything works exactly the same, but with the exception that there is no real browser or window.

Comment: Yes.I don't need exact server side rendering. Is it possible to do Isomorphic apps. If I have three components on a page <Comp1></Comp1><Comp2><Comp2><Comp3><Comp3>.Comp1 and Comp3 are mostly static .Comp2 is user specific. I don't want comp2 to be rendered in server side. Comp1 and Comp3 from server rendering and Comp2 on client side

Answer (score 6):

The way angular universal works is that components are rendere server side, and then, once the page is loaded, the client-side angular app takes over and re-render the components.

You can sometimes have some flicker while the client-side requests data from the API if you do not use State Transfer.

If all you want is not to render `Comp2` server side, then you can simply add some cndition based on the platform (browser/server)

**template.html**

```
<Comp1></Comp1>
<Comp2 *ngIf=isBrowser></Comp2>
```

**component.html**

```
import {Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {isPlatformBrowser} from "@angular/common";

isBrowser: boolean = false;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object)
{
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}
```

But note that `Comp1` will be rendered again client side anyway

Comment: This is the right answer. I would only add that https://scully.io is a project that is like Angular Universal, but much easier to use. You should consider using it for apps that use partial-pre-rendering and partial-dynamic-rendering. It is easier to use and cheaper to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will cover all your needs, but you can make the static website and use web-elements as dynamic components as it used on agular.io website. Also, you can lazily import those components on click or some other event.

Comment: Could you share documentation or examples about how to achieve this? Is it possible to use Angular Universal with angular custom elements that are lazy-inited on click? DOM already present (from SSR) but code loads on click?

Comment: All of that can be achieved creating your own renderer, here is an example. 
https://blog.nrwl.io/experiments-with-angular-renderers-c5f647d4fd9e