# How can I do partially(by component) server side rendering using angular universal?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

My problem is simple.

Is it possible to have one component rendered on server side, while another component which is in the same page NOT rendered on server side but just rendered in the original "ng serve" way?

The reason that I need this feature is bc I want some components in the page to have its own source code in "view source" page(It's for the SEO things)while the others don't.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57324844/1160794

Comment: I just read this guide today. It also covers how to include/exclude rendering per component: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-universal/

Comment: @Jette I guess that would be something what I need :D, thank you very much!